# iterate over unique elements of df.index to find minimum in column

Tags: pandas, numpy, python-3.8

My df looks like this:

```
import date time as dt

data = [{'expiry': dt.datetime(2020,6,26), 'strike': 137.5, 'diff': 0.797}, 
        {'expiry': dt.datetime(2020,6,26), 'strike': 138.0, 'diff': 0.305}, 
        {'expiry': dt.datetime(2020,6,26), 'strike': 138.5, 'diff': 0.188}, 
        {'expiry': dt.datetime(2020,6,26), 'strike': 139.0, 'diff': 0.688}, 
        {'expiry': dt.datetime(2020,7,24), 'strike': 137.5, 'diff': 0.805},
        {'expiry': dt.datetime(2020,7,24), 'strike': 138.0, 'diff': 0.305}, 
        {'expiry': dt.datetime(2020,7,24), 'strike': 138.5, 'diff': 0.203}, 
        {'expiry': dt.datetime(2020,7,24), 'strike': 139.0, 'diff': 0.703}]
df = pd.DataFrame(data).set_index('expiry')
```

am looking to find the minimum per unique index (expiry). The following works but is rather slow. Looking for a faster way to do this, either in pure python, NumPy or pandas.

```
atm_df = pd.DataFrame()
for date in df.index.unique():
    _df = df.loc[date]
    atm_df = atm_df.append(_df.loc[(_df['diff'] == _df['diff'].min())])
atm_df
```

Desired output looks like this (but don't mind if this is a df or a dict):

```
            strike  diff
expiry      
2020-06-26  138.5   0.188
2020-07-24  138.5   0.203
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use Pandas [groupby](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html) on the index and aggregate with [min](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.min.html) to get the minimum for the `diff` column. compare the result of the grouping with the values in `diff`, then index the dataframe with the resulting boolean.

```
df.loc[df['diff'].eq(df.groupby(level=0)['diff'].min())]

           strike   diff
expiry      
2020-06-26  138.5   0.188
2020-07-24  138.5   0.203
```

just a learning experience for me - Tried it out in pure python :

```
from itertools import groupby
from operator import itemgetter

#convert to dict: 
m = df.reset_index().to_numpy()

#we'll use itertools groupby
#data is already sorted so I wont bother with that
#groupby requires data to be sorted

#the first item in the sublist, expiry
#will be our grouping key
#this is our expiry value

grp_key = itemgetter(0)

#we need the rows with the minimum for diff
diff_min = itemgetter(-1)

columns = df.reset_index().columns

outcome = [dict(zip(columns, min(value,key=diff_min)))
           for key,value 
           in groupby(m, grp_key)
           ]

outcome

    [{'expiry': Timestamp('2020-06-26 00:00:00'), 'strike': 138.5, 'diff': 0.188},
 {'expiry': Timestamp('2020-07-24 00:00:00'), 'strike': 138.5, 'diff': 0.203}]
```

UPDATE: Thanks @steff for pointing me towards the dictionaries -The computation can be solved there before reading into Pandas, if necessary. We'll use the same steps involving [itemgetter](https://docs.python.org/3/library/operator.html#operator.itemgetter) and [itertools' groupby](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/itertools.html#itertools.groupby)

```
#sort data
data = sorted(data, key = itemgetter('expiry'))

outcome = [min(value, key = itemgetter("diff"))
           for _,value 
           in groupby(data,key=itemgetter("expiry"))]

outcome

[{'expiry': datetime.datetime(2020, 6, 26, 0, 0),
  'strike': 138.5,
  'diff': 0.188},
 {'expiry': datetime.datetime(2020, 7, 24, 0, 0),
  'strike': 138.5,
  'diff': 0.203}]
```

Comment: this another tad faster than Quang Hoang's solution

Comment: guessing `import itertools` and `import operator` is required for the python solution to work.

Comment: thanks @sammywemmy. one more question if you don't mind pls. How does the python solution look when I use that on the `data`  list of dicts directly?

Comment: Don’t want to give a false response. I’ll test it and get back to you

Comment: Updated the code to work on the list of dicts directly @steff

Comment: thans a million. this is by orders of magnitude faster than pandas. much appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

`min` works with `level`, and then you can use `eq` to compare the series with the extracted min:

```
df[df['diff'].eq(df['diff'].min(level=0))]
```

Output:

```
            strike   diff
expiry                   
2020-06-26   138.5  0.188
2020-07-24   138.5  0.203
```

Comment: works but is only marginally faster than my solution. thanks.

Answer (score 2):

One based on [`np.minimum.reduceat`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.ufunc.reduceat.html) -

```
sidx = df.index.argsort()
df_s = df.iloc[sidx]
I = df_s.index.values

cutidx = np.flatnonzero(np.r_[True,I[:-1]!=I[1:]])
out = np.minimum.reduceat(df_s.values, cutidx, axis=0)
df_out = pd.DataFrame(out, index=I[cutidx], columns=df_s.columns)
```

If the input dataframe is already sorted by `index`, use `df` as `df_s` directly.